# Сторонние декораторы в классе. ООП

Tags: python, ооп, декоратор

Вопрос. Почему этот код воспроизводится так как надо хотя вызова самого класса нет. Есть предположение что из-за того что была вызвана переменная `dp`, но на сколько это достоверно мне не понятно и на сколько практично.

````
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import config

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN_TESTING, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

class SheduleBot:    
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['today' ])
    async def queue(message):
        await message.reply("```\nОтправь мне в личку сообщение```\n")



#shedule_bot = SheduleBot()
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему этот код воспроизводится так как надо хотя вызова самого класса нет.

Класс как раз есть, это объекта нет.
Почему срабатывают декораторы - потому что всё внутри класса (кроме содержимого методов) выполняется сразу при загрузке модуля (тупо, если `print` внутрь класса вставить снаружи методов, он сработает при старте). Поэтому и методы создаются, и выполняются декораторы. А дальше через диспетчер просто вызываются методы, зарегистрированные декораторами.

Демонстрационный код, без асинхронности, но суть та же самая:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import List


class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = defaultdict(list)

    def message_hanlder(self, commands: List[str]):
        print("Внутри message_hanlder, commands =", commands)
        def decorator(func):
            print("Внутри декоратора на функции", func)
            # В данном случае декоратор ничем не оборачивает функцию
            # а просто регистрирует ее как обработчик команд
            # и возвращает ее же саму, а не wrapper
            for command in commands:
                self.functions[command].append(func)

            return func
        print("Выходим из message_hanlder")
        return decorator

    def send_message(self, command: str, message: str):
        for func in self.functions[command]:
            func(message)


dp = Dispatcher()


class SomeClass:
    print("Внутри класса SomeClass")

    @dp.message_hanlder(commands=["yesterday", "today"])
    def handler1(message):
        print("Handler1:", message)

    print("Между методами класса SomeClass")

    @dp.message_hanlder(commands=["today", "tomorrow"])
    def handler2(message):
        print("Handler2:", message)


print("Посылаем сообщения")
dp.send_message(command="yesterday", message="Hello!")
dp.send_message(command="today", message="Bye!")
dp.send_message(command="tomorrow", message="Hello again!")
```

Вывод:

```
Внутри класса SomeClass
Внутри message_hanlder, commands = ['yesterday', 'today']
Выходим из message_hanlder
Внутри декоратора на функции <function SomeClass.handler1 at 0x7fb610b3c1f0>
Между методами класса SomeClass
Внутри message_hanlder, commands = ['today', 'tomorrow']
Выходим из message_hanlder
Внутри декоратора на функции <function SomeClass.handler2 at 0x7fb610b3c280>
Посылаем сообщения
Handler1: Hello!
Handler1: Bye!
Handler2: Bye!
Handler2: Hello again!
```

Т.е. видно, что и `print` внутри класса сразу отработал, и декораторы выполнились сразу при старте.

Еще очевиднее будет, если вспомнить, что декоратор - это просто функция, в которую передается декорируемая функция, и возвращается другая функция (или та же самая в данном случае, но декорируемая функция регистрируется диспетчером). Поэтому класс можно переписать так:

```
class SomeClass:
    print("Внутри класса SomeClass")

    def handler1(message):
        print("Handler1:", message)

    handler1 = dp.message_hanlder(commands=["yesterday", "today"])(handler1)
    
    print("Между методами класса SomeClass")

    def handler2(message):
        print("Handler2:", message)
    
    handler2 = dp.message_hanlder(commands=["today", "tomorrow"])(handler2)
```

При этом все будет работать точно так же.

То, что декоратор является методом объекта dp, никак на результат не влияет, точно такое же поведение будет и если декоратор будет отдельной функцией.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за более развернутый ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Декораторы - это обертка, позволяющая сделать что то до функции или после, в вашем случае вызывается этот [декоратор](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/df294e579f104e2ae7e9f37b0c69490782d33091/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py#L490), который регистриует вDispatcher-e(dp) ваш обработчик сообщений и в ответ на сообщения пользователя уже использует его

Comment: Вопрос в том как он регистрируется если класс не вызван

Comment: Вы в start_pooling передаете параметр dp, start_pooling уже вызывает метод